# Attempting to filter angular array using $filter with date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I've got an array of objects from the server that has a date field in utc format.  I'd like to be able to filter using the $filter to only show the objects with the same date.

```
$scope.printData = $filter('filterstack')($scope.allActivities, {'date': $scope.reportDate});
```

I've been getting the date from the utc date on the object from the server using lodash.

```
$scope.tempDates = _.chain($scope.allActivities).pluck('date').unique().value();
```

I then edit the dates in $scope.tempDates by using a for loop to iterate through the array and slice(0,10) to get only the date and not the date/time.

Then when I attempt to filter the array I once again slice the date I'm using to search ($scope.reportDate).  Of course its not working because the date in the object is in full UTC.  Any way I can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot, I was using ISO and UTC so they wouldn't have matched up anyways.